# Form QueryBuilder with criteria the same way findBy does

Tags: php, pagination, doctrine, query-builder

I'm creating a Zend Paginator from QueryBuilder object

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator as DoctrinePaginator
use Zend\Paginator\Paginator;

[...]

protected function paginate(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, int $itemsPerPage = 10): Paginator
{
    $adapter = new PaginatorAdapter(new DoctrinePaginator($queryBuilder->getQuery()));

    $paginator = new Paginator($adapter);
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(max(-1, $itemsPerPage));

    return $paginator;
}
```

> public function findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)

I want to create a `findPaginatedBy` method in the same manner Doctrine's `findBy` method works (using a criteria array). This method will use paginate

There is no way to get a QueryBuilder or Query object out of findBy* methods so:

- Does anybody know a way to create a QueryBuilder or directly Query object by using a criteria array? through persister? or SQL?
- If it is not possible is there a library that creates a QueryBuilder or DQL in such fashion?